# How to locate pybind11 calling from python to c++

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

Trying to debug a pybind11 calling from python to c++. The breakpoints can be setup and hitted in both sides in sequence.

The function in python is
`pyspiel.load_game`
line36

https://github.com/deepmind/open_spiel/blob/master/open_spiel/python/egt/examples/alpharank_example.py

```
 game = pyspiel.load_game('kuhn_poker', {'players': num_players})
```

Tried to locate the load_game function in c++ side is LoadGame as below
https://github.com/deepmind/open_spiel/blob/master/open_spiel/python/pybind11/pyspiel.cc
line544`m.def("load_game",`
But breakpoint in this line cannot be hitted.

Then try to locate LoadGame in as below, but the breakpoint here also cannot be hitted.
https://github.com/deepmind/open_spiel/blob/master/open_spiel/spiel.cc
line259

```
    std::shared_ptr<const Game> LoadGame(const std::string& short_name,
```

Tried to look into the call stack, and randomly setup some breakpoints, the first function called out of pybind11 portion seems as below.
https://github.com/deepmind/open_spiel/blob/master/open_spiel/spiel.h
line1062

```
static std::map<std...
```

Does that means that in `LoadGame` the `GameRegisterer` is called firstly.

May I learn where should put breakpoint for the start of `LoadGame` in c++ side.

Thank you very much for your suggestion.

alex

Comment: What debugger are you using? Do you compile your pybind11 module with debug symbols?

Comment: The debugger is gdb. It is re-compiled in debug mode.

Comment: Maybe try to set breakpoint by function name and not by source line. Might be more reliable. You want to put the breakpoint in the second place you mentioned (`LoadGame`), not the first (`m.def(...`).